# How can I redirect my website to the page I want, without it autocomplete?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Some time ago, I deleted a plugin that added a "/br/" to my website.

Now it's just [www.twodogs.com](http://www.twodogs.com)

I created a redirection so that everything that was /br/ was deleted, so that the old links wouldn't stop working.

But when I access [www.twodogs.com/br](http://www.twodogs.com/br)

It kind of autocompletes the ending br with a blog that starts with br

Example:
I typed: twodogs.com/br/

The website goes to: https://twodogs.com/brasil-caiu-16-posicoes-no-ranking-global-da-felicidade/

I create this code in my website using code snippets plugin:

```
function corrigir_redirecionamento_br() {
 
   if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/br/') !== false) {
       $url_corrigida = str_replace('/br/', '/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

       wp_redirect(home_url($url_corrigida), 301);
       exit();
   }
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'corrigir_redirecionamento_br');
```

Comment: How did you implement the redirect? Your site seems to autocomplete every partial URL, not just "br". Eg. `/a` redirects to another blog page starting with "a", etc.

Comment: Same here if I test. There has to be some other logic in place in your setup. Something that fetches the first matching page or a given prefix maybe?

Comment: I  added the redirect from twodogs.com/br to twodogs.com using your own hosting.

The only redirection code is the one I mentioned above...
I don't know the reason for these redirects....

Answer (score 0):

I think you are possibly looking for [`redirect_canonical`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/redirect_canonical/). The following code hasn’t been tested, but I’m fairly certain it is at least syntactically correct.

```php
add_filter( 
    'redirect_canonical',
    static function ( $redirect, $requested_url ) {
        
        if($path = parse_url( $requested_url, PHP_URL_PATH)){
            if(str_starts_with($path, '/br')){
                return false;
            }
        }

        return $redirect;
    },
    10,
    2
);
```

Alternatively, you could just turn off the guessing mechanism:

```php
add_filter( 'do_redirect_guess_404_permalink', '__return_false' )
```

Comment: I should note that the starts with logic might be better replaced with `===` for your specific path

Comment: I tried to add this one that disables the guessing mechanism, but it gave a critical error on the site.

I put this excerpt and it worked on my company machine, but testing it now at home it keeps guessing the URL for the blogs...


Code:
function wpdocs_disable_frontpage_canonical_redirect( $redirect ) {
   if ( is_front_page() ) {
      $redirect = false;
   }

   return $redirect;
}
add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', 'wpdocs_disable_frontpage_canonical_redirect' );

Comment: Did you include a semi-colon at the end? My code is missing that.

Comment: Yes, include...